# Snakemake rule which combines the output file of different samples obtained from previous rule with no explicit output file

Tags: snakemake

I'm quite new to Snakemake and I'm facing the following problem:
I have to run a program on several folders (with the same structure) and then combine the results on the different folders in a single file. The command of this program does not require to specify an output file, but rather an output folder, which is saved as a subfolder in each "primary folder".
I have come up with the code below which, however, it is not running. I guess this is because of two different issues. One is the fact that there is not an explicit output to input relationship between the two rules (one outputs a folder, while the other wants a set of files as input). The second is that I'm not really sure that my way of creating a rule which combines the result of multiple folders is correct.

```
rule all:
    input: 
        single_folder_results = expand("test/{folder}/result_folder/quality_report.tsv", folder=dirs_list),
        results_collated = "result_total.tsv",

rule program_on_single_folder:
    input: 
        genome = "test/{folder}/{file}"
    output:
        outdir = directory("{folder}/program_result"),
    threads: n_threads
    shell:
        """
        ...
        """

rule results_collate:
    input:
        all_results = rules.all.input.single_folder_results 
    output:
        collated_results = rules.all.input.results_collated 
    shell:
        "cat {all_results} | uniq >> {collated_results}"
```

Snakemake gives the following error:

```
MissingInputException in rule results_collate in file snakemake.smk, line 50:
Missing input files for rule checkm2_results_collate:
    output: result_total.tsv
    affected files:
    ...
```

Would anyone know how to solve this?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting a specific file in your rule all but not providing a way to generate it (that snakemake is aware of).  Try to reserve `directory` for cases when you don't know the specific output files that will be produced, e.g. when splitting an input file into a variable number of parts.  In this case, you *can* specify your outputs, you do it in the rule all.

```
rule all:
    input: 
        single_folder_results = expand("test/{folder}/result_folder/quality_report.tsv", folder=dirs_list),
        results_collated = "result_total.tsv",

rule program_on_single_folder:
    input: 
        genome = "test/{folder}/{file}"
    output:
        "{folder}/program_result/quality_report.tsv",
        "{folder}/program_result/another_file.tsv",
    threads: n_threads
    shell:
```

In addition to this making your code work, if you can explicity tell snakemake all of the outputs a rule generates, it will handle partial execution and cleanup outputs properly.  Just because you list an output, doesn't mean it needs to be referenced in the rule body.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that I had to use `directory` to make snakemake handle the creation of the subfolder. Also I thought that everything that was specified in input and output had to be used within the command.